# How do I repair a missing Windows Explorer Address bar?

Tags: windows-xp

Recently after a chkdsk and reboot I lost the address bar in Windows Explorer and could not add it back. How do I bring the address bar back?

Comment: I think it would be better for future searches if you split this into a question and a self-given answer.

Comment: ...and then (I think after two days) you can even accept your own answer (or maybe someone even posts a better solution) so people know it's been solved!

Comment: done - thx for the suggestions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have been searching for weeks across many posts and today found a solution that actually works so I wanted to share that:

1. Click on Start, then Run
2. Type: REGSVR32 /i BROWSEUI.DLL
3. Close all Windows Explorer windows
4. Bring up the Task Manager
5. Kill explorer.exe (which is the running the desktop)
6. On the Task Manager, select File, then New Task (Run)
7. Type explorer.exe

Open up a new Windows Explorer, the Address Bar should now be visible.

Comment: This solution appears to be obsolete. Step 2 doesn't work in Windows 7 SP1.

Answer (score 8):

In Windows 7 this seems to happen also in normal mode if "Auto-hide" is activated in full screen mode. Put explorer into full screen mode (F11) and open system menu (alt+space). Uncheck Auto-Hide and return to normal mode (F11).