# Can Windows 7 Folder Band be restored without closing that Windows Explorer window?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have this weird behavior (i.e. bug) on my Windows 7 workstation in which folders that are automatically opened (restored) on reboot, are missing their folder band (AKA command bar):

[image]

Opening a new Windows folder window does not have this problem:

[image]

I combed the web for a solution but **none** are relevant or work in my case, as I did not modify or tweak anything in my system and if I close that Windows Explorer instance and re-open it, all is fine. However, I would like to avoid closing that Window in order to fix this Windows Explorer bug as this defeats the purpose of automatically restoring open folders on reboot.

1. [How do I repair a missing Windows Explorer Address bar?](https://superuser.com/questions/57845/how-do-i-repair-a-missing-windows-explorer-address-bar)
2. [How to Fix missing top action bar in Windows Explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/613232/how-to-fix-missing-top-action-bar-in-windows-explorer)
3. [I accidentally closed or hid the command bar - how do I restore it?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/internet-explorer-command-toolbar-windows-7/96ff06a2-799d-4bda-a883-50b61c3c1ec2)

Is there a way to restore the folder band by mere clicking something on that window or related to that window?

Comment: Just to clarify: You're accomplishing this by using the "Restore Previous Folder Windows at Logon" option for Explorer? Also you say you looked for solution but none of them worked for you -- since we're not mind readers (I'm not anyway), can you share with us exactly what you tried already (so we don't play the "I already tried that" game)? My first suggestion would be to update your video drivers.. Did you try that already? ;) If you create a new user and use them to test, does it behave the same way?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes, I'm accomplishing this by using the `Restore Previous Folder Windows at Logon` option for Explorer. I only tried the *"Right click on a blank space in the area where the command toolbar existed or where your open tabs show.  Put a check next to Command Bar by clicking on it and it will be restored (but only to newly opened windows)."*  The other fixes are for a problem that looks similar but totally irrelevant here. As for video drivers I updated to the latest and greatest. Yes, this occurs with a newly created user as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution/workaround:

In the left pane, Right-click the folder that's currently viewed > `Open in new window`.

You can now close the other "folder-bandless" window.

Comment: No answers in 3 weeks, thus accepting my own. If a better answer comes along, I will re-accept.